# slideToggle not working properly with multiple li and respected .sub_nav (div)

Tags: jquery

SlideToggle not working properly with multiple `li` and respected `.sub_nav (div)`.

**JS**

```
jQuery(".left_navigation ul li").live('click', function () {
    jQuery(".sub_nav").slideUp("fast");
    jQuery(this).find(".sub_nav").slideToggle("50");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: share your html also, possibly a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: What means "not working properly"?

Comment: Here is jsFiddle Link jsfiddle.net/ajoshi13/dsp6X

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be fine. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're getting some unexpected behavior. My guess would be because of this:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Try changing the .live() method you've got to a .on() and see how that goes.

Also, it would be helpful if you could provide a snippet of your html code so that we can see the overall structure.

Comment: I am working with the older version of jQuery so .live function is working fine but, i am doing the slideup and slidetoogle function on a same click and it is conflicting.

Comment: OK. As i and others have pointed out above, we would be able to help you better if you posted your html too. From what i can see in the Jquery above i cant really make much of it. Why are you calling slideUp() on .sub_nav without traversing to it like youve done in your slideToggle()? Maybe you need to traverse to .subNav and then run your method.

Comment: <div class="left_navigation"><ul><li class="dashboard"><a href="#">Dashboard<span></span></a> </li><li class="notifications"><a href="#">Notifications<span></span></a> <span class="count">6</span></li><li class="research_lab"><a href="#">Research Lab<span></span></a><div class="sub_nav"><ul><li><a href="#">Social Mention</a></li></ul></div></li><li class="development"><a href="#">Development<span></span></a> <div class="sub_nav"><ul><li><a href="#">Template Managers</a></li></ul></div></li></ul></div>

can't update all code so i zipped it